# AngularJS novo valor não chega na diretiva

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directives, modal

Tenho a seguinte diretiva que monta uma modal. `Arquivo: login.component.js`

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('myapp');

    app.directive('loginComponent', ['loginService', function(loginService){
        return {
            templateUrl: 'app/components/login/login.html',
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            controller: 'homeCrotroller',
            link: function ($scope) {
                $scope.submit = function() {
                    $scope.login();
                    $("#modal-login").modal('hide');
                };

                $scope.cancel = function() {
                    $scope.loggingIn = false;
                    $("#modal-login").modal('hide');
                };

                $scope.$watch('loggingIn', function() {                    
                    if ($scope.loggingIn) {
                        $("#modal-login").modal('show');
                    };
                });
            }
        };
    }]);

})();
```

E o seguinte controller. `Arquivo: home.crotroller.js`

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('myapp');

    app.controller('homeCrotroller', ['$scope', function($scope){

        $scope.loggedIn = false;
        $scope.loggingIn = false;

        $scope.showLogin = function () {
            $scope.loggingIn = true;
        };

        $scope.logout = function () {
            $scope.user = null;
            $scope.loggedIn = false;
        };

        $scope.login = function () {
            $scope.loggingIn = false;
            $scope.loggedIn = true;
        };

    }]);

})();
```

E na minha view eu chamo a função `showLogin()`

```
<a class="login" id="btn-login" href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="showLogin()" title="Entrar">Entrar</a>
```

Esta função altera o valor `$scope.loggingIn` pra `true`, só que este valor não esta chegando até diretiva. Apenas chega o primeiro status (ao carregar a tela) que é `false`

Comment: você já tentou adicionar a propriedade `scope: true` na sua diretiva?

Comment: Você pode postar o seu html para eu ver? Suspeito que o seu botão de "Entrar" esteja fora da sua diretiva, sendo assim, ele pode não ter acesso ao `controller`.

Comment: Fala @CelsomTrindade, não tentei! Por default já não é true? Mas vou tentar, posto o resultado! Valeu.

Comment: O seu erro deve ser algo simples, pois seu código parece ok.

Comment: O botão tem o acesso ao controller, pq se eu adiciono um alert por exemplo na função `showLogin()` ao clicar o alert é exibido!

Comment: Se você por o valor do loggingIn no alert, o que ele exibe após clicar?

Comment: Sim! Parece que o `$scope.$watch` não esta assistindo as alterações do loggingIn.

Comment: Uma dúvida... Se você está utilizando o directive somente para dar um show/hide.. Por que você não usa um ng-if="" ou ng-show, ao invés de ter uma diretiva para substituir o template inteiro e usar o watch para verificar?

Comment: Vou usar essa modal em varias telas, e também vou consumir um serviço de login. Você não acha interessante usar a diretiva?

Comment: É neste caso vai depender da sua estrutura. A diretiva é o melhor uso neste caso sim.. Mas me refiro ao seguinte.. No seu template de modal, use um `ng-if="loggingIn"` ao invés de trabalhar com o $watch verificando o valor. Veja se funciona

Comment: Faz sentido @CelsomTrindade! Vou fazer isso.

Comment: Já conseguiu amigo? Se conseguiu feche o tópico. Caso contrário, tente por na funcao diretiva, scope: { loggingIn: '=' } e também não se esqueça de inicializar no elemento da diretiva (<login-component loggingIn="loggingIn"></login-component>). E obviamente o loggingIn tem que vir de algum controller, claro, não do próprio controller da diretiva.